# Non-commutative exclusion constraint?

Tags: postgresql, index, exclusion-constraint

If I create the following table..

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( x int );
```

I can `EXCLUDE` the following,

```
WHERE x = <a duplicate value> (generic unique constraint)
WHERE x = <specific value>    (type of unique constraint reduce values that aren't specific to null)
WHERE x <> ANY OTHER value    (EXCLUDE WITH <>)
```

But, is there a clever way to permit

```
INSERT INTO foo (x) VALUES (0);
INSERT INTO foo (x) VALUES (1);
```

but, not

```
INSERT INTO foo (x) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO foo (x) VALUES (0);
```

Or is there a module would otherwise let me do it as a function of the index and not with a trigger.

In summary, you can insert multiple values of 1 (or 0), **but** upon the first insertion of 1 the file is closed and no further insertion of 0 can be made, but `1` can continue to be inserted.

Comment: One little question... Why would you want to do this ?

Comment: @KookieMonster I wanted to add it to this question, https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/187366/2639 Where I need the functionality

Comment: Do you want to exclude only the pair (1,0) (i.e. not allow insert of 1 when the 0 is already inserted) or any pair (b,a) where b>a?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ updated the question.